# collection.find({matchQuery}) in MongoDb is taking too long

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, aws-iot-greengrass

I am trying to read some limited records after performing a match query on find() collection in mongoDb.

The query takes forever to process.
In the next line, I try to read elements of the returned collection and that also takes a lot of time to complete.

Please help where I am making a mistake or scope of improvement.

```
robot_data = collection.find({"robot_uid": {"$eq":"12345"}},{"_id":0}).sort("_id",1).limit(500) 

 
for a in robot_data :
                print(f"print elements : {a}")
```

Regards,
Aarushi

Comment: how your document and collection looks like? Do you have index on the robot_uid field? what is the output from db.collection.getIndexes() ?  Can you provide output from: db.collection.find({"robot_uid": {"$eq":robot_uid["robot_uid"]}},{"_id":0}).sort("_id",1).limit(500) .explain("executionStats") ?

Comment: @R2D2 It is a json array document with 20 json objects. _id exists but is a guid and does not include robot_uid.  The python equivalent for _getIndexes()_ :  _db.test.index_information()_ give me empty list *{}*.  For the explain command I get the error _explain() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given_

Comment: @R2D2 Kindly also note that this piece of code takes long(for now, the execution took longer than 30 minutes and I had to interrupt the process) when executed inside a python file. However, it takes seconds when I use the python shell directly

Comment: I suspect `robot_uid` it is not indexed, and you are doing a document scan.  I suggest creating an index for `robot_uid`.   You are also omitting the id from the projection, but still trying to sort by that id, which seems a bit odd to me.  Also, this is the equivalent to your query:  `{"robot_uid" : "12345" }`.  You don't actually need $eq.

Comment: Any difference in performance if you use `robot_data = collection.find({"robot_uid":"12345"}, sort=[("_id", pymongo.ASCENDING)], limit=500)`?

Comment: ... or `robot_data = collection.aggregate([{"$match": {"robot_uid": "12345"}}, {"$sort": {"_id": 1}}, {"$limit": 500}])`? [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XdLxoKekDjj "Click me!")

Comment: @rickhg12hs I tried all combinations but no improvement. I am trying to make robot_uid an index

Comment: "However, it takes seconds when I use the python shell directly"  Are you sure the bottleneck is with `pymongo`?  Weird that using a shell is so much faster?  Is there anything else going on in the script file?

Answer (score 0):

The answer that worked out for me with everyone's help here was to make the search field *robot_uid* into an index.

The search is extremely fast now.

Thank you!
Aarushi